# MassTransit cleanup of canceled JobSaga entries

Tags: masstransit

After publishing CancelJob, pending jobs are sent to a Canceled (9) status with a Faulted timestamp and Reason of "Job Cancellation Requested". Afterwards, these produce the error "MassTransit.JobSaga Saga exception on receipt of MassTransit.Contracts.JobService.JobSlotWaitElapsed: Not accepted in state Canceled".

I have tried publishing the CompleteJob message, waiting for the timeout, etc. These cancelled entries are not completed/removed from the table. I would like to be able to remove/complete these jobs from the JobSaga table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MassTransit v8.1 will include a `FinalizeJob` command (or something like that) to take any *faulted* or *canceled* jobs and finalize them so that they are removed from the saga repository. The faulted/canceled job attempts will also be removed.